# How to pause a loop in C/C++

Tags: c, loops, animation, bgi, turbo-c

I am trying to make a screen for a car game and make the screen wait for a key to go into the next screen, thing is that with this code it changes colors too fast. I've already tried `delay()` and `sleep()` which haven't worked properly. Also, after hitting a key, it closes and doesn't wait for me to enter a key. I just want the title to blink between white and red until a key is hit, and get to know why it exits after hitting a key.

Here is my code:

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "C|\\BORLANDC\\BGI");
    outtextxy(250,280,"POINTER DRIVER 1.0");
    outtextxy(250,290,"LCCM 10070249");
    do
    {
        setcolor(WHITE);
        outtextxy(250,380,"PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
        // delay(10); nothing works here :(
        setcolor(RED);
        outtextxy(250,380,"PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
    } while(!kbhit());
    cleardevice();
    outtextxy(250,290,"HELLO"); //here it draws mega fast and then exits
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know anyone still used Borland!

Comment: If you used a better and more widely used api, like SDL or SFML, or even the Windows API, I could help you.

Comment: I'm sorry (just said so in another comment) but the professor wanted ONLY to use borland C to make graphics, also I have medium experience in java and well in C just like 1 month experience

Comment: The other guys answered already thank you for your time sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `delay(10)`, maybe try using some sort of timer variable to do this. Try something like the following (a modification of your `do-while` loop):

```
unsigned flashTimer = 0;
unsigned flashInterval = 30; // Change this to vary flash speed
do
{
    if ( flashTimer > flashInterval )
        setcolor(RED);
    else
        setcolor(WHITE);

    outtextxy(250,380,"PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");

    ++flashTimer;
    if ( flashTimer > flashInterval * 2 )
        flashTimer = 0;

    // Remember to employ any required screen-sync routine here
} while(!kbhit());
```

Answer (score 0):

`kbhit()` returns `true` if there's a character in the buffer, but doesn't remove the character before it returns. Once you reach the `getch()` line, it takes the first key that you pressed to break out of the while loop.

Possible solution: While it's a bit hacky, adding a `getch()` right after your while loop would probably fix it.

May I also suggest using ncurses instead of those Borland libraries?

Comment: We were supossed to be seeing Open GL but the  close minded professor acted as a total *** and said that he would work with borland C, I'll try what you said